# how do I set up a wired 1 to 1 network connection between two computers?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, centos, ethernet

I have two computers connected by an Ethernet cable. One is a Windows 8.1 devbox, and the other is a CentOS 7 development server with only a terminal interface (No GUI). The development server will at first only interface with the devbox.

How can I set up Windows 8.1 to enable PuTTY SSH connections to the CentOS 7 server through the Ethernet cable?

Here is a screen shot of the Network Connections dialog box in Windows 8.1 showing that it sees the Ethernet connection, but is calling it unidentified by default:

[image]

I need to learn the IP of the CentOS 7 server box and also set up home networking to make the connection happen. However what specific steps do I take to set this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no routing device between the two, you *need* to assign an IP address for each of them, additionally being both in the same subnet. So, for example, you can assign the IP address (assuming these are not used, otherwise, you need to choose a different LAN segment):

`192.168.100.1` and `255.255.255.0` to the Windows box.
`192.168.100.2` and `255.255.255.0` to the Linux box.

**For the windows machine**:

- Right click on the interface you refer on the snapshot, and click `Properties`.
- Click on `Internet Protocol Version 4 (IPv4)`
- Click on `Use the following IP address`
- As the IP address field, enter `192.168.100.1` (or a different one if this is already been used)
- As the subnet mask, enter `255.255.255.0`

**For the linux machine**:

You need to find out which interface matches your physical interface. To do that, you can access the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` directory and run `ls ifcfg-*`. You'll get one file for each network address card you have. To edit the settings of the one that is connected, assuming it's called `ifcfg-eth0`, you would run `vi ifcfg-eth0` (`vi` is the editor, you can use `nano` or `pico` or whatever you feel comfortable with), and put a content like this:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.100.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

Then you just need to run:

```
ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0
```

There's no need for a gateway since as said there's no routing (and is not needed).

Now, on the linux box, you need to make sure that the `sshd` daemon is listening to that interface too. You can check that running:

```
netstat -atpn
```

And see what is the local address for SSH. It should be something like `0.0.0.0:22`. That would mean it listens to *all* interfaces, which is what you need. If not, you'll need to edit your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and make it listen for this P2P interface as well.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I assign the IPs?  What specific steps?  Also, in CentOS, typing `netstat -atpn` results in a `command not found` error, however, I am able to `vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  Your answer is more like comments that do not give specific actionable steps that can be used by a new user.  Can you please update it with specific steps?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the details you mention. As for the `netstat` command, verify you have the `net-tools` installed, if not, install it with `yum install net-tools`

Comment: Thank you.  The windows steps worked easily, but you had me in the networking tab to set IPs.  Do I need to go in the sharing tab also and enable connections from the CentOS server?  Also, `ls ifcfg-*` resulted in `ifcfg-eno1  ifcfg-lo`.  How do your instructions change based on these results?  Finally, the CentOS server is not yet connected to the internet, so `yum` is not yet an option.  And it is not yet connected to my devbox, so I cannot `ssh` any `rpm` files in.  Do I have to establish an internet connection from CentOS?  Or is there another way?

Comment: There's no need to enable connections on the CentOS server. If you got those interfaces, then my `eth0` is your `eno1`, simply replace the naming and it should be ok. If you don't have access to internet, simply verify that the SSH daemon is listening to all the interfaces editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and checking if there's a like like `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0`. If not add it and run `systemctl restart sshd`

Comment: This works now.  Thank you and +1.  Just out of curiosity, why did you pick those ip addresses?

Comment: @CodeMed I chose those addresses because they were unlikely to be already used. They are private addresses of class C (you can google about them), and the only requirement is that both IP addresses on the boxes are in the same subnet (they do, since the network address is `255.255.255.0`), but you could have picked up any other that wasn't in use, even a different private class if you needed (you have class `A` and `B` as well)